# Is there a command-line program that can convert an image to an ASCII art image?

Tags: images, software-recommendation, batch-processing, image-processing, ascii

Is there a command-line program (for Linux) that can convert an image to ascii art and then save that output as an image e.g. jpg or png?

To illustrate what I'm in need of, I want to convert the image below into ascii art
[image]

The output that I desire from a program should be similar to this one, which was created by taking a screenshot of the output of an image-to-ascii converter (the output was pure text)

[image]

I'm aware that GIMP has the ability to save an image as ascii art and [aview](http://aa-project.sourceforge.net/aview/) can also convert an image to ascii. However, the former cannot be done via the command line and the latter only lets you view the output, not save it (I don't want to resort to taking a screenshot of the output).

I'm also aware that [libcaca](http://caca.zoy.org/wiki/libcaca) can save its output to an image, but it only outputs colourful ascii, like below.

[image]

Made by converting the source image to greyscale and then with the following command:

```
img2txt -W 70 -f tga input.jpg > output.tga
```

The reason for wanting a command-line program is to batch process a folder full of images.

Comment: I have never tried it, but I do know that it is possible to pipe text to `convert` (ImageMagick). If you set the output -f of img2txt to ansi (rather than colored ansi), you can pipe the result to convert (or other suitable software)

Comment: @horatio: convert seems to expect a file input and refuses to read from a pipe. We can do it via a temporary file anyway.

Comment: Related: https://askubuntu.com/questions/298200/is-there-a-command-line-program-that-can-convert-an-image-to-an-ascii-art-image

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use [this python code](http://motiondesigntechnology.wordpress.com/2014/03/05/python-ascii-video-and-ascii-image-creator/) I created to create ascii art from still images and videos:

https://gist.github.com/MotionDesignStudio/9374326

**Example output**

Original
[image]

ASCII art output (`python ascii_movie_image_ver_1.py cat.jpg 4 10`)
[image]

Comment: links come and go, even if it your own site... could you please add two screenshots of "before" and "after" using your code?

Comment: @Ilan I've added an example and pointed to a public git repository

Comment: The link of gist is 404 and the code and gist from tutorial is not indent correctly(mixed use of tab and space) and error prone(because of duplicated `from PIL import Image` and `import Image`. And `import ImageOps` instead of `from PIL import ImageOps`). I created [gist](https://gist.github.com/limkokhole/3a2f6d6831a41d2b34de6fb42e3f5987) to fix this.

Answer (score 19):

In case you seem to be running Linux you may stitch the applications easily together to get the desired result. This can then also be incorporated in your batch processing script.

The example below makes use of [jp2a](https://csl.name/jp2a/), a powerfull JPG to ASCII-art converter with many options to achieve desired results (consult the manpage). We then further process the resulting ASCII text file to an image using **convert** from the [ImageMagick suite](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/convert.php). Again there are many options to fine tune the result. Both applications are likely to be available from your distribution's repositories.

Below sample script will produce an ASCII-art image (format depending on the extension we give, `.jpg` is for JPEG) from an input JPEG-image. The source is rendered to 160 character width at 6 pt. This will then just fit on the default page size as pre-defined from convert.

```
#! /bin/bash
#Usage ./j2asc infile.jpg outfile.jpg

echo "converting $1 to $2"
jp2a --width=160 -i  $1 --output=tmp.txt
convert -font Courier -pointsize 6 tmp.txt $2
```

Comment: This is probably the closest I'll get to my desired output. Thanks!

Comment: Is there a way to specify the width to be something other then `835px`? I want to convert the ascii art to a `1920x1080` wallpaper image but when I pass the `-resize 1920x1080` option the width remains at `835px`.

Comment: @awashburn: image size is determined by character number (width) and pointsize. Enlarge pointsize for a larger output or scale the resulting image in a second run.

Comment: For MacOS users: jp2a is also available via homebrew and running: `brew install jp2a`.

Comment: Also consider a direct output to html in some cases: `jp2a --html --width=160 --chars="\'\"love" input.jpg --output=output.htm`. You can specify your preferred set of chars for the rendering(you will have to escape metacharacters if you want to use them). For jp2a see also [AUR](https://aur.archlinux.org/packages/jp2a/) for _Arch_.

Comment: You should double quote any variable containing a file name, otherwise your script will break on file names which contain shell metacharacters, including whitespace.  `jp2a --width=160 -i "$1"` etc.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer.

Answer (score 2):

You seem to be Using Linux, and already know libcaca. There is another lib that does exactly what you say (Image to Ascii on command line): [Aalib](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AAlib).

There are many programs do this. This one works [both on Linux and windows](http://imagetoasciiart.sourceforge.net/). Doesn't use external libraries, full source code available, etc...

Comment: As far as I'm aware Aalib can't save its output directly to an image - some method involving screenshots would need to be used, which wouldn't be reliable for large images. If there is a way to do it using Aalib could you update your answer?

The program you mentioned looks really good. Does it do batch conversion and is there a command-line interface for it?

Answer (score 1):

In Node.js Knockout 2012, there was a winning submission that took a webcam video feed and spit out an "ascii feed":

### [Asciigram](http://comorichweb.nko3.jitsu.com/)

[image: Asciigram page]

> Asciigram is a "productivity tool" that allows you to creates ASCII videos and images using your webcam. You can also create ASCII images dragging images onto the page.<sup>[[Link]](http://2012.nodeknockout.com/teams/comorichweb)</sup>

It's not exactly command line, but maybe you can retrofit it for your needs. The library they use to convert the image to ascii is called [**Jscii**](https://github.com/EnotionZ/jscii).

Comment: It only outputs text and not images. Plus, it's not a command line program

Answer (score 1):

As long as I am aware that program doesn't have a command line interface, but does convert images to text and then to images. Source is available, so you can use it to write your own tool.

You are right, aalib doesn't output images, but it does output text. As well as many other programs that work on command line.

If you're using Linux, there is a command line program called asciitopgm that will convert ascii text to a bitmap. It's part of the netpbm package.

So you can use a combination of tools:

1. aalib to draw an image using text
2. asciitopgm to create a pgm bitmap with the text file.
3. (optional) Use convert (From Imagemagick package) to convert the pgm to any other raster format you want.

I think you can do what you wanted to this way.

Answer (score 0):

I know it's a bit late, but I thought I'd post this anyway in case someone stumbles in here by chance

You can use a CLI tool I recently created, `ascii-image-converter`. It's available on snap:

```
sudo snap install ascii-image-converter
```

Or you can visit the repo if you directly want the binaries or something: https://github.com/TheZoraiz/ascii-image-converter#installation

It currently supports jpeg, png, webp, bmp and tiff image formats so it'll work on most images you encounter.

It covers all of your use-cases and can save ascii art as a png image. This command would print and save the ascii art image in the same directory:

```
ascii-image-converter myImage.jpeg -s .
```

There's a bunch more flags for more customization, including providing your own ascii character set for mapping against. You can read [the documentation](https://github.com/TheZoraiz/ascii-image-converter#ascii-image-converter) for more details. I'm working on improving it and integrating new features. Give it a try! :)